# Emit only long jump instructions instead of short jump instructions for LLVM

Tags: assembly, compiler-construction, llvm, compiler-optimization, instrumentation

Is there any easy way to make LLVM NOT emit short jump instructions with *1-byte-displacement*, like 
`75 30   JNE +30`, `eb 1a   JMP +1a`, etc; 
instead only emit *4-byte-displacement* jump instructions with 3-byte zero paddings, like 
`0f 85 30 00 00 00   JNE +30`, `e9 1a 00 00 00   JMPQ +1a`, etc.,
under the x86_64 architecture?

Apparently, this would increase the code size.

Comment: For research purposes. What does it mean to disable relaxation?

Comment: Yes, a four byte displacement is larger than a one byte displacement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `X86AsmBackend.cpp` there is a function `fixupNeedsRelaxation`. If you always return true here it should always relax e.g. Change to a full displacement.

Comment: Passing `-mc-relax-all` to the backend can be a less intrusive & cross-target alternative

Comment: Can `RelaxInstruction()` selectively choose only jump instructions to be relaxed?